# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException with nested loop remove call

Tags: java, arraylist, nested-loops, nested-lists

Trying to get some code to run but receiving `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` error when running. I think it is because I am using nested loops on the same arraylist and deleting from the index of both "concurrently". How would I avoid this problem? thanks in advance for Help .

```
for(Iterator<Missile> iteratori = missiles.iterator();  iteratori.hasNext();)
    {
        Missile missile = iteratori.next();
        if(missile.type == 2)
        {
            for(Iterator<Missile> iteratorj = missiles.iterator(); iteratorj.hasNext();)
            {
                Missile missilej = iteratorj.next();
                if(missilej.equals(missile)){
                    continue;
                }
                double cal1 =  missilej.xPos - missile.xPos;
                double cal2 =  missilej.yPos - missile.yPos;
                double radius = Math.sqrt(cal1*cal1 + cal2*cal2);
                if(radius <  missile.blastRadius)
                {
                    //collision detection is throwing array out of bounds errors 
                     missile.detonate();
                     missilej.detonate();
                     iteratori.remove();
                     iteratorj.remove();
                }
            }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

From javadoc of [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> The iterators returned by this class's `iterator` and `listIterator` methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own `remove` or `add` methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Since your two iterators (`iteratori` and `iteratorj`) are iterating the same list, `iteratori.remove()` will cause `iteratorj.remove()` to throw the error.

Since `missiles` is an `ArrayList`, you can iterate using indexes (`int i` and `int j`) and then remove using `missiles.remove(i)` and `missiles.remove(j)`. Of course, you'll have to adjust your index values as you remove items in the list.

Comment: Would that mean that I would have to iterate through the whole array each time for each remove? Would that would be slower than how I have things set up at the moment? or do I just not understand what you mean.

Comment: Your loops will be similar, but using `for (int i = 0; i < missiles.size(); i++)` and `Missile missile = missiles.get(i)` and `missiles.remove(i)`.